# Mysql different Counts for different tables. Is it possible in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-5.7

MySql Production Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)

I can test on Mysql version 8

I have these tables:

- nms_alert (id, user_attended_id)
- nms_alert_not_attend (nms_alert_id, not_attend_id)
- nms_employee_log (begin, end, zone_id)

I would like to have something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    # COUNT(accept),<-- How to find this?
    # COUNT(reject),<-- How to find this?
    nms_employee_log.id as idLog,
    nms_employee_log.begin as employeeBegin,
    nms_employee_log.end as employeeEnd,
    nms_employee_log.zone_id
    FROM  nms_employee_log where employee_id= 11

    (GROUP BY idLog)
```

Where the 'accepted' are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            nms_alert.id as accept, 
            nms_employee_log.id as idLog,
            nms_alert.alert_begin as dataAlert,
            nms_employee_log.begin as employeeBegin,
            nms_employee_log.end as employeeEnd,
            nms_employee_log.zone_id
            FROM `nms_alert`  
            INNER JOIN nms_employee_log on ( nms_employee_log.begin <= alert_begin AND nms_employee_log.end >= alert_begin )
            WHERE nms_employee_log.employee_id= 11  AND  INSTR( nms_alert.sent_to_zones , nms_employee_log.zone_id )
            AND nms_alert.user_attended_id=3 
        ORDER BY nms_employee_log.id DESC


accept  idLog        employeeBegin      employeeEnd   zone_id   
64077   805     2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-17 19:32:24 25
64077   766     2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-16 16:16:07 25
62202   712     2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 25
62202   709     2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:41 25
55526   530     2019-12-03 16:13:43 2019-12-03 19:40:59 25
53800   427     2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 24
53800   426     2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 26
53824   425     2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 25
53800   425     2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 25
53579   389     2019-11-27 07:42:24 2019-11-27 14:09:45 24
53437   386     2019-11-26 15:17:04 2019-11-27 07:48:32 25
52570   332     2019-11-22 19:15:54 2019-11-23 10:23:52 25
52596   332     2019-11-22 19:15:54 2019-11-23 10:23:52 25
52535   328     2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 25
52538   328     2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 25
52570   328     2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 25
52515   327     2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 24
52515   323     2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 16:04:56 24
52399   306     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 25
52328   306     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 25
52337   306     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 25
52396   306     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 25
52328   305     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 26
52399   305     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 26
52328   304     2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 27
```

and the  'rejected' are:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            nms_alert.id as reject, #<-- Count Rejected
            nms_employee_log.id as idLog,
            nms_alert.alert_begin as dataAlert,
            nms_employee_log.begin as employeeBegin,
            nms_employee_log.end as employeeEnd,
            nms_employee_log.zone_id
            FROM `nms_alert`  
            INNER JOIN nms_alert_not_attend on nms_alert.id = nms_alert_not_attend.nms_alert_id 
             INNER JOIN nms_employee_log on ( nms_employee_log.begin <= alert_begin AND nms_employee_log.end >= alert_begin )
            WHERE nms_employee_log.employee_id= 11  AND  INSTR( nms_alert.sent_to_zones , nms_employee_log.zone_id )
            AND nms_alert_not_attend.not_attend_id = 3  
        ORDER BY nms_employee_log.id DESC



reject  idLog       employeeBegin      employeeEnd   zone_id    
64757   803     2019-12-16 20:05:07 2019-12-17 19:30:29 27
64089   784     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 27
64187   784     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 27
64092   783     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 25
64175   783     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 25
64177   783     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 25
64181   783     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 25
64089   780     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 27
64092   778     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 25
64175   778     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 25
64177   778     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 25
64181   778     2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 25
64083   768     2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-16 16:16:07 27
64012   761     2019-12-16 13:20:13 2019-12-16 14:32:38 25
64010   756     2019-12-16 12:59:37 2019-12-16 13:20:06 25
62262   728     2019-12-13 21:44:54 2019-12-13 21:57:14 25
62223   723     2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 25
62227   723     2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 25
62223   720     2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 25
62227   720     2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 25
62202   712     2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 25
62202   709     2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:41 25
56664   631     2019-12-05 10:45:09 2019-12-07 22:03:28 26
56657   630     2019-12-05 10:45:09 2019-12-07 22:03:28 25
56661   630     2019-12-05 10:45:09 2019-12-07 22:03:28 25
```

The result I need:

```
accept reject idLog    employeeBegin        employeeEnd    zone_id
1       0       805 2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-17 19:32:24 25
0       1       803 2019-12-16 20:05:07 2019-12-17 19:30:29 27
0       2       784 2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 27
0       4       783 2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:23:44 25
0       1       780 2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 27
0       4       778 2019-12-16 16:16:35 2019-12-16 19:16:12 25
0       1       768 2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-16 16:16:07 27
1       0       766 2019-12-16 15:10:04 2019-12-16 16:16:07 25
0       1       761 2019-12-16 13:20:13 2019-12-16 14:32:38 25
0       0       760 2019-12-16 13:20:13 2019-12-16 14:32:38 26
0       0       758 2019-12-16 12:59:37 2019-12-16 13:20:06 27
0       0       757 2019-12-16 12:59:37 2019-12-16 13:20:06 28
0       1       756 2019-12-16 12:59:37 2019-12-16 13:20:06 25
0       0       755 2019-12-16 12:59:37 2019-12-16 13:20:06 26
0       0       754 2019-12-13 21:57:22 2019-12-16 12:57:30 27
0       0       753 2019-12-13 21:57:22 2019-12-16 12:57:30 28
0       0       752 2019-12-13 21:57:22 2019-12-16 12:57:30 21
0       0       751 2019-12-13 21:57:22 2019-12-16 12:57:30 22
0       0       730 2019-12-13 21:44:54 2019-12-13 21:57:14 23
0       0       729 2019-12-13 21:44:54 2019-12-13 21:57:14 24
0       1       728 2019-12-13 21:44:54 2019-12-13 21:57:14 25
0       0       727 2019-12-13 21:44:54 2019-12-13 21:57:14 26
0       0       726 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 27
0       0       725 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 23
0       0       724 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 24
0       2       723 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:44:32 25
0       0       722 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 26
0       0       721 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 27
0       2       720 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 25
0       0       719 2019-12-13 20:50:27 2019-12-13 21:26:39 26
0       0       718 2019-12-13 20:47:23 2019-12-13 20:50:01 27
0       0       717 2019-12-13 20:47:23 2019-12-13 20:50:01 28
0       0       716 2019-12-13 20:47:23 2019-12-13 20:50:01 21
0       0       715 2019-12-13 20:47:23 2019-12-13 20:50:01 22
0       0       714 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 23
0       0       713 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 24
1       1       712 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 25
0       0       711 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:47:04 26
0       0       710 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:42 27
1       1       709 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:41 25
0       0       708 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:41 25
0       0       707 2019-12-13 20:18:28 2019-12-13 20:46:42 27
0       0       706 2019-12-13 19:06:04 2019-12-13 20:18:06 27
0       0       705 2019-12-13 19:06:04 2019-12-13 20:18:06 25
0       0       704 2019-12-13 19:06:04 2019-12-13 20:18:06 27
0       0       703 2019-12-13 19:06:04 2019-12-13 20:18:06 25
0       0       702 2019-12-13 14:22:59 2019-12-13 19:05:43 27
0       0       701 2019-12-13 14:22:59 2019-12-13 19:05:43 25
0       0       700 2019-12-13 14:22:59 2019-12-13 19:05:43 25
0       0       699 2019-12-13 14:22:59 2019-12-13 19:05:43 26
0       0       698 2019-12-12 14:43:13 2019-12-13 14:22:36 27
0       0       697 2019-12-12 14:43:13 2019-12-13 14:22:36 25
0       0       696 2019-12-12 14:43:13 2019-12-13 14:22:36 27
0       0       695 2019-12-12 14:43:13 2019-12-13 14:22:36 27
0       0       694 2019-12-12 14:11:20 2019-12-12 14:42:27 25
0       0       693 2019-12-12 14:11:20 2019-12-12 14:42:27 27
0       0       692 2019-12-12 14:11:20 2019-12-12 14:42:27 25
0       0       691 2019-12-12 14:11:20 2019-12-12 14:42:27 27
0       0       690 2019-12-12 14:08:50 2019-12-12 14:10:54 25
0       1       631 2019-12-05 10:45:09 2019-12-07 22:03:28 26
0       2       630 2019-12-05 10:45:09 2019-12-07 22:03:28 26
1       0       530 2019-12-03 16:13:43 2019-12-03 19:40:59 26
1       0       427 2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 24
1       0       426 2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 26
2       0       425 2019-11-28 15:08:00 2019-11-29 14:28:07 25
1       0       389 2019-11-27 07:42:24 2019-11-27 14:09:45 24
1       0       386 2019-11-26 15:17:04 2019-11-27 07:48:32 25
2       0       332 2019-11-22 19:15:54 2019-11-23 10:23:52 25
3       0       328 2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 25
1       0       327 2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 21:18:04 24
1       0       323 2019-11-22 13:33:31 2019-11-22 16:04:56 24
4       0       306 2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 25
2       0       305 2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 26
0       1       304 2019-11-21 12:20:01 2019-11-22 08:14:38 27
```

====

**What would be the best query or queries to achieve this?**

And the best performance?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect as well.

Comment: @GMB Is it clear?

Comment: Not quite. Your result does not seem to match your sample data. And you have `x`s where you should really be showing the actual values that you expect.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and state which version of MySQL you're using

Comment: You can get those sums mixed with the rest of the columns using window functions. They are available in MySQL 8.x, but not in MySQL 5.x. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @The Impaler. Now the version is Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)

Comment: Just to be clear, the `user_attended_id` is a user ID such as would be found in `employee_id` and `not_attend_id` columns are an ID of the alert, as may be found in `nms_alert.id`?

Comment: @user1683793 yes in this example user_attended_id= 3 and employee_id=11. This values can set. One is for the UserId the Other is for the employeeId

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. It help a lot to make it also clear for myself. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the initial question, this should be doable using a `CTE` (if you are on MySQL 8+) or a subselect and `CASE SUM`

```
SELECT 
     SUM(case when accept is not null then 1 else 0 end) as countAccept
    ,SUM(case when reject is not null then 1 else 0 end) as countReject
 FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
    nms_alert.id as accept, 
    nms_alert_not_attend.nms_alert_id as reject, 
    nms_alert.alert_begin, 
    nms_employee_log.zone_id,
    nms_employee_log.device_type,
    nms_employee_log.model,
    nms_employee_log.wifi_network
    FROM `nms_alert`  
    INNER JOIN nms_alert_not_attend on nms_alert.id = nms_alert_not_attend.nms_alert_id 
    INNER JOIN nms_employee_log on ( nms_employee_log.begin <= alert_begin AND nms_employee_log.end >= alert_begin )
    WHERE nms_alert_not_attend.not_attend_id = 3 
    AND nms_alert.user_attended_id=3 
    AND nms_employee_log.employee_id= 11
) s
```

Comment: It gives this error: 
Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0) Do I have to do something in MySql to accept WITH?

Comment: @InêsGomes What version of MySQL are you using? A subselect should work as well.

Comment: Thank you @wp78de. Is not giving error now, but not giving the result I expected. I remake the question, so maybe now is more clear?